# Access 2010 - Cannot edit textbox in unbound form which is populated by recordset

Tags: forms, textbox, edit, recordset

I am using Access 2010 with linked tables from SQL Server 2008.  I have a form that I am populating using a recordset and the control source of the textbox in this form is set to a field from the recordset.  I find that although I can navigate through all the 16 records on the form, and the form loads correctly, I am unable to edit the Notes text box.  It needs to be editable.  The textbox has Enabled=True and Locked=False.  The AllowEdits property of the form is set to true.  All the tables in the query have primary keys.  So, is it my query then - since it has right and inner joins in it? So the issue is that I cannot type in the textbox.

Just a little background, I tried using a query as the recordsource for this form, but found that Access' AutoSave feature inserted incomplete records into my Result table, in addition to the updates and inserts done by my Save button event.  If the only way to circumvent this is to ask the user whether he/she would like to save changes every time he navigates, then that would be way too frustrating for the end user.  So, I have had to use an unbound form where I use VBA to populate it using a ADO recordset.

Incidentally, I can edit the DocID and DocumentType columns, it's the fields from the query that cannot be changed (QCNote)

Here is the code from my Form_Open event.  I also have a Form_Current event that disables the Submit button for inapplicable categories.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 

Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn

DocID = [Forms]![QCDocAttributes]![DocID]

DocumentType = [Forms]![QCDocAttributes]![Document Type]

strSQL = "SELECT " & DocID & " AS DocID,'" & DocumentType & "' AS DocumentType,     QC_QCDecisionPoint.Description, QC_QCDecisionPoint.QCDecisionPointID , QC_QCResultDecisionPoint.QCNote FROM QC_QCResultDecisionPoint RIGHT JOIN ((QC_QCAttribute INNER JOIN QC_QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc ON QC_QCAttribute.QCAttributeID = QC_QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc.QCAttributeID) INNER JOIN QC_QCDecisionPoint ON QC_QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc.QCDecisionPointID = QC_QCDecisionPoint.QCDecisionPointID) ON QC_QCResultDecisionPoint.QCDecisionPointID = QC_QCDecisionPoint.QCDecisionPointID WHERE (((QC_QCAttribute.Description)= '" & [Forms]![QCDocAttributes]![AttributesDropdown] & "' ));"

.Source = strSQL
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
.Open
End With
Set Me.Recordset = rs

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```